# Mountain Lion reboots while connection to iPad 3

Tags: itunes, ipad, macos, mac

I have installed Mountain Lion recently. I have been using 4th generation iPod Touch for development, and it was working fine.

Once I had to debug something on iPad 3, the OS reboots every time I plug the USB adapter with my iPad 3. if the device is plugged in from the beginning then the OS reboots as soon as I login. Does anyone else here face the same issue ?

Comment: Which Mac do you have? How much charge does the iPad have?